# Runtime free error while deleting user space stack

Tags: c++, assembly, memory-management, inline-assembly

I am trying to create a user space stack and run functions using this stack.
Following are the steps I am doing.

1. Allocate a space for the stack.
2. Before calling a function, switch the stack pointer to the new location.
3. Also try to store previous or original stack pointer
4. Return of the called function
5. Restore the original stack pointer

I implemented the following based on the above points:

```
/* Ubuntu 18.04 x86_64 */
/* Compiler gcc version 7.5.0 */
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>
#include <memory>

class Thread {
public:
    
    /* stack will point to lowest addr of th User Stack */
    unsigned char * stack = nullptr;
    
    /*stack_ptr will point to the Highest addr of the User Stack */
    unsigned char* stack_ptr = nullptr;

    int stack_size = 0;

    Thread() {
        stack_size = 16*64; // 1024 B
        stack = new unsigned char[stack_size];
        /*stack_ptr points to the highest memory of this space*/
        stack_ptr = stack + stack_size;
    }
    
    ~Thread() {
        std::cout <<"User stack deleted"<< std::endl;
        if(stack != nullptr)
            delete[] stack;
    }
    void func(int x,int y) {
        std::cout <<"Hello from the func ["<<x<<"] ["<<y<<"]"<< std::endl;
    }
};
int main() {
    /* createa a User level Thread */
    Thread t;

    /* Some random local variable */
    // int a[100];

    unsigned char* stk = t.stack_ptr;
    
    /* Note: rsp = current stack top */

    uint64_t prev_stack = 0;        /* for assert checking */
    uint64_t x = 7; /*some random value, just for stack alighment of 16B */
    
    asm("movq %%rsp, %%r11\n\t"     /* save current stack ptr to r11(or rax etc.) */
        "movq %%r11, %[out1]\n\t"   /* just for assert check later */
        "movq %[in1], %%rsp\n\t"    /* change rsp to stk, i.e. to our own stack top */ 
        "pushq %%r11\n\t"           /* Push r11 or prev stack ptr to current stack */       
        "pushq  %[in2]\n\t"         /* for stack alignment only */
        :[out1] "=m" (prev_stack)   /*just for assert check later */
        :[in1] "m" (stk),[in2] "m" (x)          /* two inputs */
        :);


    // call the func, this func
    // will will use our own stack

    t.func(1,2);
    
    /*just for checking x */

    uint64_t y;
    uint64_t _prev_stack;
    asm(
        "popq %[out1]\n\t"          /* y = stack.pop() */
        "popq %%rsp\n\t"            /* restore stack: rsp = stack.pop() */
        "movq %%rsp, %[out2]\n\t"   /* just for checking */
        :[out1] "=m" (y),[out2] "=m" (_prev_stack) /* two outputs */
        :
        :
    );

    assert(prev_stack == _prev_stack && "Main's stack not restored!");
    std::cout <<std::hex<<"Stack restored = "<< prev_stack << std::endl;

    assert(x == y && "x and y are not equal!!");
    std::cout <<"Program Ended!" << std::endl;
}
```

I have added couple of extra checks, just for debug purpose.

The following output is generated:

```
Hello from the func [1] [2]
Stack restored = 7ffd55eb8ea0
Program Ended!
User stack deleted
munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer
[1]    27337 abort (core dumped)  ./a.out
```

It seems that, I can safely (?) return to the original function, because the instruction pointer is restored automatically (due to `callq` and `retq` operation sequence, gcc compiler did this) and  the program also gets back the original `rsp` or the stack top. The `rbp` pointer is also taken care of by the compiler.

But I get an error in the `destructor` of the `Thread class`.

I tried to debug on my own using gdb, but I could not find any reason for observed the error:
Here are the output of the `gdb backtrace`

```
_GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:51
51  ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c: No such file or directory.
>>> bt
#0  __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:51
#1  0x00001555545f2801 in __GI_abort () at abort.c:79
#2  0x000015555463b897 in __libc_message (action=action@entry=do_abort, fmt=fmt@entry=0x155554768b9a "%s\n") at ../sysdeps/posix/libc_fatal.c:181
#3  0x000015555464290a in malloc_printerr (str=str@entry=0x15555476a7a8 "munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer") at malloc.c:5350
#4  0x0000155554649ecc in munmap_chunk (p=0x614e60) at malloc.c:2846
#5  __GI___libc_free (mem=0x614e70) at malloc.c:3117
#6  0x0000000000400e2d in Thread::~Thread() ()
#7  0x0000000000400bdc in main ()
```

However valgrind shows no leaks.

```
==27982== HEAP SUMMARY:
==27982==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==27982==   total heap usage: 3 allocs, 3 frees, 74,752 bytes allocated
==27982== 
==27982== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
```

(Although valgrind warns : `Warning: client switching stacks?`, I think it is normal w.r.t to the above code)

**Observation:** If I comment out the `if(stack != nullptr) delete[] stack` line, error goes out
but valgrind shows the following:

```
=28019== 1,024 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 1
==28019==    at 0x4C3089F: operator new[](unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==28019==    by 0x108ED7: Thread::Thread() (test.cpp:20)
==28019==    by 0x108BBD: main (test.cpp:36)
```

I am really confused with the memory free error and no leak status. What could be the cause of such memory deallocation error ? Am I doing any mistake while saving and restoring old and new stacks ?

Thanks.

**Update**

I simplified the code:

```
/* Ubuntu 18.04 x86_64 */
/* Compiler gcc version 7.5.0 */
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>
#include <memory>


const int _stack_size = 16*64; // 1024B


void func(int x,int y) {
    std::cout <<"Hello from the func ["<<x<<"] ["<<y<<"]"<< std::endl;
}

int main() {

    unsigned char * stackBase = new unsigned char[_stack_size];
    unsigned char * stackTop = stackBase + _stack_size;

    std::cout <<"Before "<<std::hex <<(void*)(stackBase) << std::endl;

    asm volatile("movq %%rsp, %%r11\n\t"    /* save current stack ptr to r11(or rax etc.) */
                "movq %[in1], %%r12\n\t"
                "movq %%r12, %%rsp\n\t"     /* change rsp to stk, i.e. to our own stack top */ 
                "pushq %%r11\n\t"           /* Push r11 or prev stack ptr to current stack */
                // "pushq %%rbp\n\t"        
                : /*no input */
                :[in1] "m" (stackTop)           /* two inputs */
                :"r11","r12","rsp");

    func(1,2);
    
    asm volatile(
                "popq %%rsp\n\t"    /* restore stack: rsp = stack.pop() */
                :/* no outputs */
                :/* no inputs */
                :"rsp");

    std::cout <<"Program Ended!" << std::endl;
    std::cout <<"After "<<std::hex<<(void*)(stackBase) << std::endl;
    delete[] stackBase;
}
```

But it still shows the `double free` error:

```
Before 0x555e80926e70
Hello from the func [1] [2]
Program Ended!
After 0x555e80926e70
double free or corruption (out)
[1]    4343 abort (core dumped)  ./a.out
```

Error in runtine with `-fsanitize=address` option:

```
Before 0x619000000080
ASAN:DEADLYSIGNAL
=================================================================
==5605==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: stack-overflow on address 0x618ffffffb90 (pc 0x14b656131576 bp 0x619000000418 sp 0x618ffffffb98 T0)
    #0 0x14b656131575  (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasan.so.4+0x51575)
    #1 0x14b655e39039 in std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<< <std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*) (/usr/local/gcc-10/lib64/libstdc++.so.6+0x12c039)
    #2 0x564202743e4b in func(int, int) (/home/deka/Academic/userLevelThread/a.out+0x2e4b)
    #3 0x5642027445ca in main (/home/deka/Academic/userLevelThread/a.out+0x35ca)
    #4 0x14b654c1cb96 in __libc_start_main (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x21b96)
    #5 0x564202743d49 in _start (/home/deka/Academic/userLevelThread/a.out+0x2d49)

SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: stack-overflow (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasan.so.4+0x51575) 
==5605==ABORTING
```

Comment: First, you overwrite `r11` but do not put a clobber for `r11` in.  This could be the cause of the error.  Then, note that local variables may be placed on the stack, so after you change `rsp`, access to local variables won't work.  It's usually best to write a stack-switching function entirely in assembly (not even in inline assembly) to sidestep these issues.

Comment: Also, the `m` constraints in your inline assembly are likely to generate `rsp`-relative memory addresses (check the assembly output with `-S`).  Since you have changed `rsp`, the writes go to who knows where.  And this line: `t.func(1,2);` already tries to access a local variable that may have been on the old stack you just switched away from.

Comment: Consider using `ucontext` for stack switching.  Using a well-known and tested interface avoids many of the difficulties that come from switching stacks yourself.

Comment: Hi @fuz I simplified the code. Please check If I miss any points you mentioned.

Comment: Any approach based on inline assembler violates the rules of inline assembly your code will not work reliably, regardless of how often you simplify it.  Do not switch stacks in inline assembly.

Comment: However, I'll try to figure out what the issue is for you.

Comment: Note: I get a bus error for your code, because depending on how it is compiled, the stack may be aligned to 8 or 0 bytes modulo 16 but an alignment to 0 bytes modulo 16 is required on function calls.  This too is nearly impossible to address in inline assembly.

Comment: Apart from this, I cannot reproduce the issue you have.  But that's not suprising: your approach fundamentally cannot work and what error you get from it is essentially random as you overwrite the stack without the compiler knowing about it.

Comment: Hi, "overwrite the stack without the compiler knowing about it" -- this line, I did not understand

Comment: In inline assembly, you must not modify the stack in any way.  You may not even push or pop values as the compiler may place data into the red zone.  However, you modify it drastically (by switching the stack).  This can't work.  I'll repeat it again: you cannot switch stacks in inline assembly and expect it to work.  Use `ucontext` instead which was designed for this purpose or write a stack switching function entirely in assembly.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs. I will try ucontext header.